# Android AsyncTask copy and update every second

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would like to copy a file in the background and update the progress every n seconds.

Right now the code below updates the progress when the new percentage is greater than the previous percentage. This falls apart for small files since it goes so fast and lags the UI thread.

So my question is how to copy a file in the background and but publish the progress every n seconds. Also how can i calculate the speed its copying at?

A good example of what i am trying to mimic is a download notification, it shows the speed, percentage and updates them at ~2000ms intervals

This is the code I am using to copy, in the `doInBackground()` method

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    FileInputStream input = null;
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    totalMegaBytes = new File(source).length();
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(source);
        output = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte [] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            total += length;
            latestPercentDone = (int) ((total / (float) totalMegaBytes) * 100);
            if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
                percentDone = latestPercentDone;
                publishProgress(""+percentDone);
            }
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //flush remaning information
        output.flush();
        //close stream
        output.close();
        input.close();
```

Comment: You should definitely consider Rx for this kind or problem, it would be much easier to do this : https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the `publishProgress` calls, and call it only in predefined intervals.

Simply add a minimum time interval for the updates. For example, this will update at a maximum of half a second rate:

```
private static long UPDATE_DELAY = 500; // Delay in millis

// Start with 0 progress
publishProgress("0");

...

long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if ((currentTime - startTime > UPDATE_DELAY) &&
    (percentDone != latestPercentDone)) {
    percentDone = latestPercentDone;
    publishProgress(""+percentDone);
    startTime = currentTime;
}

...

// End with 100 progress
publishProgress("100");
```

Comment: This will first wait half a second, but then publish the progress every iteration of the loop.

Comment: That was just a general direction. But fixed it anyway, just to be on the safe side. Thanks.

Comment: @RobMeeuwisse: `startTime` is being updated after every call to `publishProgress()`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the way to report once every so much time is to use a loop like this:

```
long reportTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // first report after first processing
while (!done) {
    // do processing
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= reportTime) {
         // do progress report
         reportTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000; // next report in 2 secs
    }
}
```

Calculating copying speed can be done different ways. The easiest way is just to divide the current bytes copied by the current runtime:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalBytesCopiedSoFar = 0;
while (!done) {
    // do processing, and update totalBytesCopiedSoFar
    if (itIsReportingTime) {        
        long runTimeSoFarInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        long runTimeSoFarInSecs = runTimeSoFarInMillis / 1000;
        double copyingSpeedInBytesPerSec = (double) totalBytesCopiedSoFar / (double) runTimeSoFarInSecs;
    }
}
```

Combining the two patterns and applying it to your code gives the following. I've left out your setup and clean up code, so this doesn't compile, but you can get the idea.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long reportTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // first report as soon as possible
long totalMegaBytes = new File(source).length();
while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    total += length;

    latestPercentDone = (int) ((total / (float) totalMegaBytes) * 100);

    long runTimeInSecs = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
    double speedInBytesPerSec = (double) total / (double) runTimeInSecs;

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= reportTime) {
        publishProgress(""+latestPercentDone); // you may want to report the speed as well
        reportTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000; // next report in 2000 ms
    }

    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
```